# insert tab and CR/LF based on the node name

Tags: xml, xslt, formatting, xslt-1.0, xmlnode

I have an XML file which contains sport results, but they need to be formatted and organized for better reading/understanding, I believe the formatting should be based on the name of the node (testing the node name maybe?), like if the name is "tab" then insert a tab... my xml file is as follow:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Header>
      </Header>
      <Body><p><p><b><u>Wednesday 14 December 2016</u></b></p><p></p><p>10:30<tab>Atletico Nacional  </tab><tab>v</tab><tab>Kashima Antlers  </tab><i><tab><tab>(Suita City Football Stadium)</tab></tab></i><b><tab><tab></tab></tab></b></p></p><p><p><b><u>Thursday 15 December 2016</u></b></p><p></p><p>10:30<tab>Club America  </tab><tab>v</tab><tab>Real Madrid  </tab><i><tab><tab>(Yokohama International Stadium)</tab></tab></i><b><tab><tab></tab></tab></b></p></p></Body>
    </Message>
```

and the expected result should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>  
<!DOCTYPE NEWS SYSTEM "structure.dtd">  
<OBJECT>  
<ID>12345</ID>  
<HEADER>SPORTS NEWS</HEADER>  
<OBJECT_BODY>  
Wednesday 14 December 2016  
10:30 Atletico Nacional v Kashima Antlers *(Suita City Football Stadium)*  
Thursday 15 December 2016  
10:30 Club America v Real Madrid *(Yokohama International Stadium)*  
</OBJECT_BODY>  
</OBJECT>
```

Your help and support is much appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: Is your output a text file? How exactly do you intend to format it?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and post the expected output *as code** there.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, my output method is XML, basically I try to transform this XML file to another XML file based on a schema file for a specific News-system to read. (I have updated my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I see entirely how you arrived at the expected output, but try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Message">
    <OBJECT>  
        <ID>12345</ID>  
        <HEADER>SPORTS NEWS</HEADER>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Body"/>
    </OBJECT>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Body">
    <OBJECT_BODY>  
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </OBJECT_BODY>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tab">
    <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="i">
    <xsl:text>*</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>*</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If necessary, add additional templates to handle `b` and `u` elements.

Comment: the example I put here is just a small portion of the whole XML document and my XSLT file is also a very long sheet that's why I couldn't copy them all in here... but I got the idea from your answer and it works perfectly now... Many thanks for your useful answers and support.

Comment: There is just one more optional thing if you can help me with, how to format "i" node text to "italic" or to "Bold"? I have tried many text formatting ways but they didn't workout for me.

Comment: @JohnMiller XML is a plain-text format; there is no way to "format" it as italic or bold. The only thing you can do is add some sort of markup.